# Why window.location is not directing to view page in yii framework

Tags: javascript, yii

```
function addCart(){
    //alert('"hello"');
    var cart_id = $('input[name="cart\[\]"]:checked').map(
                              function(n){return this.value;}
                         ).get().join(',');
    //alert(cart_id);
    <?php
    echo Chtml::ajax(array(
                'url'=>array('language/addtocart'),
                'type'=>'post',
                'data'=>'js:{cart_id:cart_id}',
                'success'=>'js:function(){window.location="test"}', 
                ));
    ?>
}
```

Comment: Because `http://test` is not a valid URL for you. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use window.location.href and a proper url

```
 window.location.href="http://localhost/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
'success'=>'js:function(){window.location="test"}',
```

With:

```
'success'=>'js:function(){location.href="test"}',
```